# Select sites on Area 51 are down

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Last week, I got the downed flying saucer on Area 51, now I'm getting it again when I try to view proposals. This seems to not affect commitment phase proposals.

[image: Saucer down]

Seems to be an issue in both FF and Chrome, so I don't think it's a browser issue.

Some specific ones I can't see:

Arts:

- [Filmmaking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85123/filmmaking)
- [Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80865/literature)
- [Graphic Art Critique](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89147/graphic-art-critique)

Culture:

- [Scandinavian Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82505/scandinavian-languages)
- [Language Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning)
- [Polish Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/81892/polish-language)
- [Alternative History](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79097/alternative-history)
- [Paranormal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84880/paranormal)
- [Klingon Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88590/klingon-language)
- [Culture Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87039/culture-exchange)
- [Aliens](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80090/aliens)
- [Comics and Cartoons](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89305/comics-and-cartoons)
- [Slavic Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89568/slavic-languages)

Life:

- [Homeschooling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75548/homeschooling)
- [Humor](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88145/humor)
- [Feminism & Gender Equality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87013/feminism-and-gender-equality)
- [Brain & Bio Hacking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82541/brain-bio-hacking)
- [Equality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87275/equality)
- [Emergency Preparedness](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89744/emergency-preparedness-prepping)
- [Educational Resource Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89684/educational-resource-recommendations)

Professional:

- [Public Speaking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/78918/public-speaking)
- [Systems Thinking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85615/systems-thinking)
- [Urban Planning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88933/urban-planning)
- [Educators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82415/educators)
- [Engineering Careers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88569/engineering-careers)

Recreation:

- [Trains](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/81747/trains)
- [RC & Scale Modeling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82797/rc-scale-modeling)
- [Game Mechanics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80264/game-mechanics)
- [Costuming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79160/costuming)
- [Book Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87408/book-recommendations)
- [Blacksmith & Metalwork](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88630/blacksmith-and-metal-work)
- [The Armory](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88721/the-armory)
- [Birdwatching](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86829/bird-watching)

Science:

- [Futuristic Technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80810/futuristic-technology)
- [Science Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84646/science-exchange)
- [Open Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90201/open-science)
- [Image Processing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/image-processing-and-computer-vision)
- [Thinking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75846/thinking)
- [Aerospace Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76047/aerospace-engineering)

Seriously... every single one of these is related to aliens somehow... except maybe Trains... but... really.. Clearly this outage is showing us what we don't know about Aliens... they're into LARPing, trying to understand what makes us laugh and are planning to invade through Northern Europe... and, of course, they need to know where we are, technologically.

Some seem to be fine:

- Every proposal in the "[Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/2/business)" section is fine.
- [Music Production](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82083/music-production)
- [Writing Critiques](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82417/writing-critiques)

I didn't check closed proposals.

Comment: I can see newest proposals like a charm. No-repro here.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Can you see this one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/proposals/85123/filmmaking

Comment: Ahh, I see it. Are they making a movie about saucers? ;) BTW seriously you should exactly say what link makes saucers crash. The aliens know where you live . . .

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I checked a couple and they all seemed to be broken, except for the one I checked that is in commitment... so I assumed that it was all of them.

Comment: @Catija Yep... I can repro. It's broken

Comment: Completed... mostly. Now something new is broken. I'm on it.

Comment: @Anna let me guess, aliens are behind all of this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Look at the sites that are down... Paranormal, Klingon... Aliens... Hardly an accident.

Comment: @Catija extraterrestrial accident...

Comment: Open Science has just kicked the bucket, so it's not supposed to show up.

Comment: All the links are to the error page. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @HDE226868 Closed sites still show up on the list, though... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68765/stack-overflow-in-korean

Comment: @Catija Weird. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Catija what I meant was that nearly all your links were of the form `http://area51.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/proposals/...` which would always show the error page even if the proposal was OK.

Comment: I don't see how this is [meta-tag:status-completed] though. I'm seeing the error page for these proposals as well.

Comment: @ChrisF Basically, I saw the report, assumed it was the issue I just fixed, and figured my time was better spent fixing than retagging back. :)

Comment: Fix for the second issue is rolling out shortly.

Comment: You can stop going through all of the proposals. ;) We can see exceptions, no need for a perfect list here.

Comment: @Catija Should be all fixed now. Thanks for the report! I just want to make  sure y'all aren't wasting time. :)

Comment: Looks fine now.